# Can I work around these padding issue in AES 256 ECB due to Reed solomon encoding?

Tags: aes, padding, ecb

Disclaimer: I do **NOT** believe AES-ECB to be at all useful for encryption. That said, due to time and bureaucratic issues that I'm not in control of, I need to use AES-ECB.

I get packets of data that are Reed Solomon encoded. Each reed solomon encoded packet has length 255 bytes. On decoding, I get the message which is 223 bytes. (This is RS(255,223) with 8-bit symbols. Each codeword contains 255 code word bytes, of which 223 bytes are data and 32 bytes are parity).

I must now encrypt this data (223 bytes) and then RS encode it again to get back a packet of 255 bytes. However, when using AES ECB in block cipher mode, a byte of zeroes has to be padded in before encryption.

This padding yields a ciphertext that is 224 bytes long. This can't be RS encoded as the packet is required to be 223 bytes.

I realize that hoping this can be solved with a block cipher might be impossible, but any help or workarounds would be really appreciated!

Comment: You cannot get a ciphertext of 223 bytes using ECB. It is not a multiple of the blocksize. You either have to use a stream-cipher mode of AES, or encrypt a smaller amount of plaintext, pad the ciphertext to the appropriate size, then encode.

Comment: Can you use AES-ECB on a string of 14 unique 16-byte blocks to simulate an AES-CTR one-time pad and xor a 223-byte prefix of that with your data?  (Warning: As a one-time pad you can't use it again!  If your messages have sequence numbers, use the message sequence number as (say) the low 64-bit half of each 16-byte block and the block sequence number within a message as the high 64-bit half of each block.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ciphertext stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing#ECB_ciphertext_stealing) as the padding mode and the length won't be increased, see: [ECB ciphertext stealing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ciphertext_stealing#ECB_ciphertext_stealing) .

Comment: This is over UDP, so not sure how I'd deal with packet loss in this case.

Comment: In what manor is CTS related to packet loss? Different that other packet loss?